# Optimizing PHP code that uses a lot of for loops

Tags: php, c++, c, actionscript-3, optimization

My PHP code contains a lot of foreach loops and results are absolutely disastrous. It takes way too long to run.

Is there an alternative to this. I am open to all suggestions.

I am thinking may be implementing a flash based client and using actionscript to utilize the client's CPU for running the logic.

Or is there a way to use C/C++ to handle the computationally demanding part on the server itself and return PHP the results.

The following function gets called 1,000,000 times.

```
public function performEnrichmentAnalysis($geneSet) {
    /**
     * $mainArray is a multi dimentional array.
     * EntrezID | Set (0/1) | pValue | rank
     */
    $mainArray = array();
    $finalArray = array();
    $originalGenesScore = 0;
    $randomGenesScore = 0;
    $u = 0;
    $EntrezID = array();
    $Set = array();
    $pValue = array();
    $Rank = array();
    $originalGenes = $geneSet->getGenes();
    $memeberCount = $geneSet->getGeneCount();
    $randomGenes = $this->geneExpressionData->getRandomGenes($memeberCount);
    /**
     * Copy the elements of original and random gene sets to main array.
     */
    foreach ($originalGenes as $key => $value) {
        $pVal = $this->geneExpressionData->getExpressionValue($value);
        $array = array('EntrezID' => $value, 'Set' => 0, 'pValue' => $pVal, 'Rank' => 999);
        array_push($mainArray, $array);
        unset($array);
    }
    foreach ($randomGenes as $key => $value) {
        $pVal = $this->geneExpressionData->getExpressionValue($value);
        $array = array('EntrezID' => $value, 'Set' => 1, 'pValue' => $pVal, 'Rank' => 999);
        array_push($mainArray, $array);
        unset($array);
    }
    /**
     * sort the multi dimentaional array based on p-values
     */
    foreach ($mainArray as $key => $row) {
        $EntrezID[$key] = $row['EntrezID'];
        $Set[$key] = $row['Set'];
        $pValue[$key] = $row['pValue'];
        $Rank[$key] = $row['Rank'];
    }
    array_multisort($pValue, SORT_ASC, $mainArray);

    /**
     * Assign ranks to the genes
     */
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($mainArray); $index++) {
        $row = $mainArray[$index];
        $row['Rank'] = $index + 1;
        $row['Score'] = 0;
        //print_r($row['Rank']);
        array_push($finalArray, $row);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate scores for each gene
     */
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($finalArray); $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($finalArray); $j++) {
            if ($finalArray[$j]['Set'] != $finalArray[$i]['Set']) {
                $finalArray[$i]['Score']++;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate score for the entire set and get universal U and z score.
     */
    for ($counter = 0; $counter < count($finalArray); $counter++) {
        if ($finalArray[$counter]['Set'] == 0) {
            $originalGenesScore += $finalArray[$counter]['Score'];
        }
        if ($finalArray[$counter]['Set'] == 1) {
            $randomGenesScore += $finalArray[$counter]['Score'];
        }
    }

    if ($originalGenesScore > $randomGenesScore) {
        $u = $randomGenesScore;
    } else {
        $u = $originalGenesScore;
    }

    $zNumerator = $u - (($memeberCount * $memeberCount) / (2));
    $zDenominatorSquared = ($memeberCount * $memeberCount * ($memeberCount + $memeberCount + 1)) / 12;

    $z = $zNumerator / sqrt($zDenominatorSquared);

    if (abs($z) > 2.303) {
        $this->temp001++;
    } elseif (abs($z) > 1.605) {
        $this->temp005++;
    } else {
        $this->tempRemaining++;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code if you want us tobhelp you optimize. Alo code optimization might be more on topic at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I think your question is a little too vague. You're not telling us anything about the kind of data you're traversing in those loops, and the computations you're running.

Comment: Right, thanks. I posted the code now.

Comment: I don't want to use PHP and I am looking for alternatives. But it has to be a web based app so any alternatives?

Comment: PHP is the wrong technology to do this. Write it in C/C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not really something that can be easily answered. Yes, assuming you know C++, the code can be rewritten in C++. I don't see any major obstacles for that.

You would have to come up with a way to get your original `geneSet` to the C++ code, and then construct a tructure to represent your `$mainArray` and other . Use `std::vector` for your arrays.

Since this code doesn't actually generate any webcontent itself, you could quite easily just replace the function with a call to C++ program installed on the server. I would suggest that you actually implement the functionality that CALLS this function in C++, since if this is called 1M times, then you'd better do 1M calls in C++, rather than calling a piece of C++ code 1M times.

Comment: Thank you Mats Peterson
I am new to PHP and client-server development. I will rewrite this in C++ and also make the calls from the C++ program but I am not clear about how to call the C++ code from PHP. I want to send a linked list and an array from the PHP code to the C++ class which will work and then return an array back.

What are the steps I should follow?

Comment: I assume that calling this function 1M times takes several seconds, right? So it would be perfectly reasonable to write the input data to to a file, use `exec()` [or some similar PHP function] to execute a C++ program, and provide the output result in a file (or on `stdout` that can be captured).